# Is there a new C++ syntax assuming .template after member name?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, c++17

I am coding inside a template class

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class MyMap {
   ...
   std::map<K, V> m_map;
```

and wishing to write

```
   m_map.insert(...
```

but `CLion` code completion inserts for me

```
   m_map.template insert()
```

Is this a bug or a new C++ syntax? If new syntax, then what is it?

Comment: I don't think this is new syntax, just more verbose. Not sure if there is any ambiguity that can be solved using the long form https://godbolt.org/z/4EncEvToz.

Comment: Furthermore, a lot of `insert` overloads are not templates as we can see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: note that visual studio doesn't accept this code: https://godbolt.org/z/4eoPKx45q

Comment: @Timo sorry, I meant "new for me" of course. What is the name of this construct?